# Loop within a Loop within a Loop within a Dream within a Dream

Tags: javascript, json, nested-loops

I'm trying to work with some API's and in return they give me a huge JSON object and I need to compare it with my JSON object, however, I have so many loops that it's just not funny anymore.

My current object looks like this:

```
var courses = {
    art_117: {
        course_folder: true,
        sco_id: "12111",
        subFolders: [{
            folderName: "SET_01",
            isFolder: true,
            number: 1,
            sco_id: "121116"
        }, {
            folderName: 'SET_06',
            isFolder: true,
            number: 6,
            sco_id: '121117'
        }]
    }
}
```

The returning object looks like this:

```
var json = {
    "status": {
        "code": "ok"
    },
    "scos": {
        "sco": [{
            "name": "SET_01",
            "url_path": "/134123/",
            "is_seminar": "false",
            "sco_id": "63453452",
            "folder_id": "12111",
            "type": "folder",
            "icon": "folder",
            "display_seq": "0",
            "duration": "",
            "is_folder": "1"
        }, {
            "name": "SET_02",
            "url_path": "/f4r8y3l0sy6/",
            "is_seminar": "false",
            "sco_id": "123413",
            "folder_id": "12111",
            "type": "folder",
            "icon": "folder",
            "display_seq": "0",
            "duration": "",
            "is_folder": "1"
        }, {
            "name": "SET_03",
            "url_path": "/f7d6lf2xbb1/",
            "is_seminar": "false",
            "sco_id": "12341234",
            "folder_id": "12111",
            "type": "folder",
            "icon": "folder",
            "display_seq": "0",
            "duration": "",
            "is_folder": "1"
        }]
    }
}
```

Here's my current code

```
if (typeof json.scos.sco != 'undefined') {
    var scos = json.scos.sco;
    var len = scos.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        var id = scos[i]['folder_id'];
        var name = scos[i]['name'];
        for (var j = 0; j < keys.length; j++) {
            if (adobe.courses[keys[j]]['sco_id'] == id) {
                var subFolders = adobe.courses[keys[j]]['subFolders'];
                for (var k = 0; k < sections.length; k++) {
                    if (sections[k]['folderName'] == name) {
                        courses[keys[j]]['subFolders'][k]['sco_id'] = scos[i]['sco_id'];
                        courses[keys[j]]['subFolders'][k]['isFolder'] = true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How can that be rewritten so that there isn't 3 nested loops?

Comment: `keys.length` what is `keys`? i don't see a reason for more than two loops.

Comment: What are those `sco_id`s? Could they be used for a global, efficient lookup structure?

Comment: keys.length is a list of the object keys in my original json object.

Comment: sco_id's are the folder id's that are returned from the json object that I store in my current object